# How to access services in gitlab ci?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci

I think I'm losing my mind over this one. I'm trying to start up a PostgreSQL database in my gitlab-ci.yml file. As far as I know, I should be able to access it via postgres:5432. However, it doesn't work; my web app, which also runs in a Docker container, cannot access it.

This is the relevant part of my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy_test:
  image: docker
  stage: deploy_test
  services:
    - name: postgres
      alias: postgres
    - name: docker:23.0.6-dind
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker run -e DATABASE_URL="postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB" -d -p 8080:80 --name $TEST_APP_CONTAINER_NAME $CI_REGISTRY/$APP_CONTAINER_URL:$VERSION
    # Wait for the web app to be ready
    - timeout 300s sh -c 'until status_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://$TEST_APP_CONTAINER_NAME:8080); [ "$status_code" -eq 200 ]; do sleep 5; echo "HTTP Status Code= $status_code"; docker ps -a; docker logs $TEST_APP_CONTAINER_NAME; done'
    - echo "Test web app is ready!"
```

And this is the output from my wait-loop:

```
HTTP Status Code= 000
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
8bb3f101174e   registry.gitlab.com/X/testapp/testapp:v1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago   Exited (1) 4 seconds ago             e2e_container
> start:migrate:prod
> prisma migrate deploy && npm run start
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgresdb", schema "public" at "postgres:5432"
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
npm notice
```

I got some questions:

- Why is there no container for the databse when running "docker ps -a"? I thought the services are also started using separate docker containers?
- I read about docker networks. Is my webapp in another network and is this the reason this doesn't work?
- In this case, how can I check if my database is really running from the script, before starting my webapp?
- And finally, any help for getting this to work is truly appreciated.

Comment: I might be missing something but your jobs runs in a container using the docker image. That continer is linked to the db container using its alias name. But then inside the image you run a shell command to create another docker container. the new container wont be linked to the DB container, why are you spawning docker containers inside docker container? why not just set the image of the job to what ever image your using in your manual container. Gitlab will only link the postgres service to the container running the job not to any other containers you create your self

Comment: Assuming you are using gitlab.com shared runners or have correctly setup dind on your self-hosted runner, try adding the feature flag variable `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "1"` and add `--network=host` to the to your docker run command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69844200/5747944) and its answer for an example of this and explanation of how the networking works and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804452/5747944) for communicating with containers you create with the `docker:dind` service from your job.

Comment: @sytech you are my hero! It works now, thank you!
Can you tell me how I can reach my app container now? My timeout still fails, the HTTP Status Code is still 000 when trying to reach http://$TEST_APP_CONTAINER_NAME:8080

Comment: @zabze I'm not 100% sure the answer to that. Elsewhere, I've stated that you can't do that while using `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD`, but I'm not so confident about that anymore. It may very well be possible, but I'm not sure how, exactly. I will try to figure out the answer. One initial thought is you might be able to launch another container that can reach the app container by attaching it to the same "host" network or explicitly linking it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I managed to do it, the container is reachable via dind, the correct connection string is http://dind:8080 (i used a "dind" alias for docker-dind to do this).
Wow, what a relief that it works now. Still got a lot to learn here :)